How does more tension and torsion make catapults more effective?
I understand that catapults use potential energy stored in a rope to launch a projectile further. However, I am unclear how stretching out the rope (tension) and twisting it (torsion) make the projectile go farther. Does it have to do with an increase in potential energy? Thanks!

The rope is a spring. If you stretch or twist a spring, you store potential energy in it.

I was wondering more how this affects the arm of the lever and therefore the projectile.

Good point. No doubt it bends and acts like a spring too.
